# Print multiple Word documents to PDF

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

**Challenge**: To print multiple Word documents(from 2 to 10 docs Max) to single PDF

**Available Data:** Documents and their locations to be printed

**Logic used:** Loop through recordset of a query which has all the document paths

**Hitting the wall:** couldn't find a best way to do this?

```
Dim WordObj As Object
Set WordObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Dim strSql As String
strSql = QryLinkstoDocs

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenSnapshot)
Dim fileName As String
 Do While Not rs.EOF
     fileName = rs.Fields(0) 'This field has the link to the files
     WordObj.Documents.Open filename

     'WordObj.PrintOut Background:=False 'This works for single file 

     WordObj.PrintToFile "C:\Temp.pdf", collate = True
     rs.MoveNext
Loop
WordObj.Quit
Set WordObj = Nothing
```

Comment: If you can swing the cost, I really like Aspose. I am pretty sure OpenXML can do it as well, and that is free. I like Aspose better, but I didn't give OpenXML a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the job:

Basically I created a new word doc and inserted the contents from each file into it and at the end,Print the single doc to PDF.

```
Do While Not rs.EOF     
         fName = rs.Fields(0)

        If FileExists(fName) Then
          oApp.Selection.InsertFile _
          FileName:=CStr(fName), Range:=""
          oApp.Selection.InsertBreak
        Else
          Debug.Print "The File is missing"
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
Loop
oApp.Activedocument.PrintOut Background:=False
```

Answer (score -1):

I've always liked [pdftk (pdf toolkit)](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). I haven't used it since they added the GUI and increased functionality, but there is a pretty simple command-line interface that allows you to combine, separate, etc PDFs. You could write a simple script in Access that generates a list of the files to combine and then sends the command-line code to execute.

An example from their readme:

```
Join in1.pdf and in2.pdf into a new PDF, out1.pdf
     pdftk in1.pdf in2.pdf cat output out1.pdf
or (using handles):
     pdftk A=in1.pdf B=in2.pdf cat A B output out1.pdf
or (using wildcards):
     pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
```